# Antlr4 is printing 'Extraneous input' error even with expected input

Tags: antlr4

I'm trying to parse [SMILES](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simplified_molecular-input_line-entry_system) strings using the [OpenSMILES](http://www.opensmiles.org/spec/open-smiles-2-grammar.html) specification.

The grammar:

```
grammar SMILES;

atom: bracket_atom | aliphatic_organic | aromatic_organic | '*';

aliphatic_organic: 'B' | 'C' | 'N' | 'O' | 'S' | 'P' | 'F' | 'Cl' | 'Br' | 'I';
aromatic_organic: 'b' | 'c' | 'n' | 'o' | 's' | 'p';

bracket_atom: '[' isotope? symbol chiral? hcount? charge? atom_class? ']';
symbol: element_symbols | aromatic_symbols | '*';
isotope: NUMBER;
element_symbols: UPPER_CASE_CHAR LOWER_CASE_CHAR?;
aromatic_symbols: 'c' | 'n' | 'o' | 'p' | 's' | 'se' | 'as';

chiral: '@'
        |  '@@'
        |  '@TH1' | '@TH2'
        |  '@AL1' | '@AL2'
        |  '@SP1' | '@SP2' | '@SP3'
        |  '@TB1' | '@TB2' | '@TB3' | DOT DOT DOT | '@TB29' | '@TB30'
        |  '@OH1' | '@OH2' | '@OH3' | DOT DOT DOT | '@OH29' | '@OH30';

hcount: 'H' |  'H' DIGIT;

charge: '-'
        |  '-' DIGIT
        |  '+'
        |  '+' DIGIT
        |  '--'
        |  '++';

atom_class:':' NUMBER;

bond: '-' | '=' | '#' | '$' | ':' | '/' | '\\';
ringbond: (bond? DIGIT |  bond? '%' DIGIT DIGIT);
branched_atom: atom ringbond* branch*?;
branch: '(' chain ')' |  '(' bond chain ')' |  '(' dot chain ')';
chain: branched_atom
    |  chain branched_atom
    |  chain bond branched_atom
    |  chain dot branched_atom;
dot: '.';

DOT: .;
DIGIT: [0-9];
NUMBER: DIGIT+;
UPPER_CASE_CHAR: [A-Z];
LOWER_CASE_CHAR: [a-z];

ONE_TO_NINE: [1-9];

smiles: chain;

WS: [ \t\n\r]+ -> skip ;
```

When trying to parse the following using AntlrWorks2's TestRig:

```
CCc(c1)ccc2[n+]1ccc3c2Nc4c3cccc4
```

The following error(s) are printed (shortened for brevity):

```
line 1:5 extraneous input '1' expecting {'*', '[', 'N', 'O', 'I', 'S', '%', ')',..., DIGIT}
...
line 1:31 extraneous input '4' expecting {<EOF>, '*', '[', 'N', 'O',..., DIGIT}
```

This happens for every digit that is encountered in the string.

**EDIT 1**

After fixing the `DOT` rule, as suggested by @Lucas Trzesniewski, the `extraneous input` error has disappeared. However, a new error is present now when testing a different SMILES string.

For example, testing:

```
[Cu+2].[O-]S(=O)(=O)[O-]
```

Produces the error:

```
line 1:1 no viable alternative at input 'C'
```

**EDIT 2**

Problem from **EDIT 1** was due to my `element_symbols` rule. Using the literal symbol strings seems to have solved it.

```
element_symbols: 'H' | 'He' | 'Li' | 'Be' | 'B' | 'C' | 'N' | 'O' | 'F' | 'Ne' | //...and so on
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your lexer rules are wrong.

First error:

```
DOT: .;
```

This is a catch-all. What you really mean is:

```
DOT: '.';
```

Second error: You're getting confused with the following rules:

```
DIGIT: [0-9];
NUMBER: DIGIT+;
ONE_TO_NINE: [1-9];
```

`ONE_TO_NINE` will never match anything, because it's included in `DIGIT`, and `DIGIT` appears first. As the `ONE_TO_NINE` rule is never used, so you should simply remove it.

Then, things like `DIGIT DIGIT` in your parser rules won't match either if you're expecting a 2-digit number, you'll get a `NUMBER` token there unless you separate the digits with whitespace (I don't know what you really mean there so perhaps it's not an error).

Comment: Thanks for the help. Fixing the `DOT` rule has made that error disappear but now a new error is present with a different SMILES string. For example, `[Cu+2].[O-]S(=O)(=O)[O-]` produces the error `line 1:1 no viable alternative at input 'C'`.