# ANTLR4: extraneous input caused by a rule not being tested

Tags: antlr4

The actual grammar I'm working with is much larger but this snippet illustrates my problem.

```
grammar test ;

word: CHAR(CHAR|DIGIT)* ;

DIGIT: [0-9] ;
CHAR: [a-z] ;
OR: 'or' ;
```

When testing the rule `word`, any words containing a sub string of "or" produce an extraneous input error. For example:

hello : FINE
antidisestablishmentarianism : FINE
h**or**se : ERROR

Why is ANTLR picking this up? The `or` isn't even used.

I'm fairly sure that this is the [same problem this person had](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26206148/antlr4-is-printing-extraneous-input-error-even-with-expected-input) but I'm having trouble making sense of it.

Answer (score 1):

The `CHAR` rule matches text with a length=1; the `OR` rule with a length=2. So, the lexer will choose the `OR` rule to match any `or` text sequence in preference to the `CHAR` rule.

That is, the lexer will choose rules based first on longest match, and then on grammar order.

Comment: Hey, thanks. Is there a simple solution to this? I'm struggling to understand WHY this is the case. As I understood ANTLR (not very well apparently), it shouldn't be looking for the `or` so it shouldn't catch it. In my actual grammar I have lots more rules like this such as `an` and `for`. I've been googling round for a while but I can't find a solution.